# Cannot join chars into string in csv writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csvwriter

I want to save my result into csv file. This is my code:

```
import itertools
import csv

letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

combinations = list(itertools.permutations(letters, 4))
print(len(combinations))

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for item in combinations:
        wr.writerow("".join(item))
    myfile.close()
```

the .csv result is:

```
"A","B","C","D"
"A","B","C","E"
"A","B","C","F"
...
```

what I expect is:

```
"ABCD"
"ABCE"
"ABCF"
...
```

I am new in python but I don't know why this occur, because when I write `"".join(item)` in the loop, I got what I want. Can you help me?

what i expect is:

```
"ABCD"
"ABCE"
"ABCF"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writerow() interprets the string you pass as a sequence of characters. This causes the function to write each character as a separate field. Instead of passing `"".join(item)` you can pass `["".join(item)]` to treat them as a single field

```
import itertools
import csv

letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

combinations = list(itertools.permutations(letters, 4))
print(len(combinations))

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for item in combinations:
        wr.writerow(["".join(item)])
    myfile.close()
```